# Как заменить символ в строке на другую строку?

Tags: python

Проблема заключается в том, что такие команды работают просто так

```
s = "e"
s = s.replace("e", "E*x(t)")
# s = "E*x(t)"

print(s)
```

А вот допустим у нас массив из символов и нужно поменять соответствующий символ на формулку

```
if elements[i] == "e":
    elements[i] = elements[i].replace("e", "E_{depth}_{i} * x_{depth}(t)".format(depth=depth, i=i))
            # elements[i] = "E_{depth}_{i} * x_{depth}(t)".format(depth=depth, i=i)
elif elements[i] == "v":
    elements[i] = "eta_{depth}_{i} * diff(x_{depth}(t),t)".format(depth=depth, i=i)
```

то выкидывает ошибку `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: как выглядит этот *массив символов*?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите заменить `i`-ый элемент строки на то, что вам нужно, то метод `replace` вам не помощник.
Это можно сделать так:

```
string = 'Hello'

elements = []
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i]=='e':
        elements.append(f'E_{i}')
    elif string[i]=='o':
        elements.append(f'O_{i}')
    else:
        elements.append(string[i])
new_string = ''.join(elements)
print(new_string)
```

Используя словарь для замен, можно сократить код:

```
string = 'Hello'
replacements = {
    'e': 'E_{}',
    'o': 'O_{}',
}

elements = []
for i in range(len(string)):
    elements.append(replacements.get(string[i], string[i]).format(i))
new_string = ''.join(elements)
print(new_string)
```

А если еще и везде вызов метода `format` будет одинаковый (одинаковые аргументы):

```
string = 'Hello'
replacements = {
    'e': 'E_{}',
    'o': 'O_{}',
}

new_string = ''.join(
    replacements.get(string[i], string[i]).format(i)
        for i in range(len(string))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня Ваш код работает, но я добавила входной массив. Думаю, у вас он многомерный.
Внимательнее посмотрите на исходный массив.
У меня так:

```
elements =["e", "v","","ev"]
depth =0
for i in range(len(elements)):
 if elements[i] == "e":
  elements[i] = elements[i].replace("e", "E_{depth}_{i} * x_{depth}(t)".format(depth=depth, i=i))
            # elements[i] = "E_{depth}_{i} * x_{depth}(t)".format(depth=depth, i=i)
 elif elements[i] == "v":
  elements[i] = "eta_{depth}_{i} * diff(x_{depth}(t),t)".format(depth=depth, i=i)
  
print(elements)
```

[image: Результат:]